# Changing Button Text on Content Type form

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I created a content type called "video" and I created a module named df_video.module with:

```
function df_video_video_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Upload');
}
```

I am trying to change the button text of my Video content type form from "Save" to "Upload" but nothing seems to work when I hit refresh. I also tried clearing the cache. I've tried many variations of the function name with no success. I would prefer to use the specific name of the form in the function name so I don't need to do a switch statement.

Also, just out of curiosity does anyone know if there is something special for placing hooks in a .inc.php file? Not doing this currently but I'm thinking it would just be an include to the main module file.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7? It can be achieved differently depending on your Drupal version.

Comment: Drupal 7. Sorry for not including that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot target only the `video_node_form` with an existing hook in D7, but you can target all node forms and then check against the node type to alter the form. Take a look at the documentation and comments on [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). It may also help to check out how the [Book module implemented this hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_form_node_form_alter/7) in D7.

```
function df_video_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form['#node'];
  if ($node->type == 'video') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Upload');
  }
}
```

With regard to your second question, you generally want to place your hooks in the `.module` file so that they are guaranteed to be picked up by Drupal. There are some cases where this is not necessarily necessary, like in [hook_views_api()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) where you can points to a file containing other views-specific hooks.

Comment: You may need to clear your cache again. If you inspect element of the page and search for the `form_build_id`, that should be different if it has reloaded the form.

Comment: I could have sworn I cleared the cache but after a little of time, it started to work. Thank you!